# Tensorflow memory problems with validation data

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, ram, tensorflow-datasets

Im trying to train a tensorflow neural network. Since the training data is too big for my computer RAM I have divided it into sub-datsets and sequentially train them. I have a problem however, if I call `model.fit` with the validation_data parameter the code returns an error. I i do not pass any validation data I works perfectly.

```
epochs = 30
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = read_val(3, val_ratio=0.5)
print("start training")
for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("\n" + str(epoch))
        for n in range(3):
            x_t, y_t = read_small(n)
            history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
            x_t = []; y_t = [];
```

The `read_small(n)` essentially reads the sub-dataset for the training data. If call the function as:
`history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0)`the full training is accomplished for the 30 epocs and no error is returned.

However if I call the function as given in the code:
`history = model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))` the program returns the following error:

*"C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\CVISEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 477. MiB for an array with shape (125000, 1000) and data type float32*

But the error happens at around epoch number 15, so it's not like the computer lacks RAM to read the validation data. What could be the problem? Does `model.fit` generate a copy of the validation data every time the function is called even though I already read them before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that `x_t = []; y_t = []` is not enough to delete the loaded training data, and that garbage accumulates over time, eventually filling the memory. A more definitive approach would be `del x_t, y_t`.

In general, we can use the `tf.data` pipeline to manage datasets and to avoid loading all data at once. Probably check the [intro](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) in the docs. Something like the following (**can't guarantee it will work**):

```py
x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = read_val(3, val_ratio=0.5)

# Assuming x_val has shape [N, D], y_val has shape [N, 1]
x_val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_val)
y_val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_val)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(x_val, y_val)
val_ds = val_ds.batch(100)  # Validate on 100 examples at a time

...

# Then pass `val_ds` when training the model: 
model.fit(..., validation_data=val_ds)
```